# Row Visibility in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services

I am new to SSRS report, I am having data as below

[image]

I need to display the data as below format

[image]

Please give me some details how to group the columns, and conditional display of rows in the tablix grid. I have tried but row visibility condition not working and I am getting US region also for Samuel employee with Asia region data

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you do NOT want to use Row Visibility. You just need to show the data, if there's no data for a region, it will not appear.

Add a List and Group By Manager and Dept. This will Group your data by manager.

Add a Column. Add 2 Rows Inside Group. Make 1 for the Manager and the other for the Dept. Make the 3rd row big enough for the Employee/Region data.

Add a Table and group by Region. Add your fields. Put the table in the List box. Since the table is inside the list, the list will show the records for the manager in the list.

Here's what it should look like when the list is selected:

[image]

And here's what the inner table would look like:

[image]